# find the frame or position from the content drawn on the screen

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics

I'm new to core graphics in ios. 
I have a string like

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hi Guys How are you ? Just visit the http://www.apple.com and if not satisfied then go to http://www.google.com and Again if you visit http://www.msn.com"];
```

Now i have drawn above string using

[str drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f,40,300,200)
    withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize]
        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap
    alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

It is drawn on the screen very fine. I wan to find that on which position i have drawn 
http:// www.apple.com

Basically I need to find the frame at which place http://www.apple.com has been drawn?
Bcoz i need to detect above URL and when user tap on above URL i wan to find that url in the web page.

is it possible?